# Various questions about SVG

Tags: svg

Is it possible to have an image tag that displays the image at the original size of the image without explicitly specifying that size?

Is it possible to center an image without explicitly moving it by half the image's size?

Is it possible to scale an image using something other than the default scaling method? I want to use nearest neighbor.

Comment: You can if you're prepared to do it with javacscript. Load it into an image object, get the natural width/height from that and then construct an image element with that width/height and associate the image object with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have an image tag that displays the image at the original size of the image without explicitly specifying that size?

No.  Specifying a width and height is necessary.

> Is it possible to center an image without explicitly moving it by half the image's size?

Yes, But you'll need to be more specific. Centre w.r.t. what?  Centre vertically, horizontally, or both?  Achieving the first two is easy. The last one is trickier.

Remember, SVG has no real automatic layout.  It is intended that you specify the position and size of all graphical elements.

> Is it possible to scale an image using something other than the default scaling method? I want to use nearest neighbor.

You can specify `image-rendering="pixellated"`, but its browser support is spotty.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering